# Джойстик при клике получает координаты 0, 0

Tags: c#, unity3d

При клике либо нажатии и удержании джойстик получает координаты близкие к нулю и смещается в левый нижний угол.

При движении мышкой или пальцем он остается на отдалении по диагонали к левому нижнему углу на расстоянии половины расстояния BG.

В чем проблема такого стартового его поведения?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ActorMobileController : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler {

private Image joystickBG;
[SerializeField]
private Image joystick;
private Vector2 inputVector;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    joystickBG = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystick = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();

}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{

    OnDrag(ped);

}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{

    inputVector = Vector2.zero;

    //Возврат джойстика в центр
    joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;

}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{

    Vector2 pos;
    if(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(joystickBG.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {

        //Получение координат позиции касания джойстика
        pos.x = (pos.x / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        inputVector = new Vector2(pos.x * 2 - 1, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(inputVector.x * (joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2), inputVector.y * (joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2));

    }
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    print("input" + inputVector);
    if (inputVector.x != 0) return inputVector.x;
    else return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

}

public float Vertical()
{

    if (inputVector.y != 0) return inputVector.y;
    else return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

}

}
```

конкретно вот этот узел

```
//Получение координат позиции касания джойстика
pos.x = (pos.x / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
pos.y = (pos.y / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
```

получая координаты например 40, 40, на выходе дает значения близкие к нулю. Почему же?

Comment: Документацию читай по rectTransform.sizeDelta. Это не всегда то как выв его используете.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html